# NLTK FreqDist no longer working

Tags: python, nltk, frequency-distribution

I'm relatively new to python and NLTK, but I wrote a program that used FreqDist from NLTK. It's been working as intended for the last week but today it returned: 'FreqDist' object has no attribute 'most_common'

Does anyone have any idea as to why this is? Like I said, everything was working fine prior to this and I didn't make any changes to the code.

edit: Here is the relevant code:

```
from nltk import FreqDist

fdist1 = FreqDist(input_list)
frequency_output = fdist1.most_common(150)
```

Not sure what else is necessary - the input list is a list of words. Was working fine last night...

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show the relevant code?

Comment: Assuming you didn't mistype `most_common` or insert invisible characters: Either your program corrupts the `fdist1` object, or your nltk source is corrupted. Try printing `dir(fdist1)` and look for `most_common`.

Comment: @alexis I had similar problem (nltk.__version__ '2.0.5'), but the dir(fdist1) didn not contain most_common. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As long as input_list is iterable this should work fine. What is the type of input_list. Are you running this as a stand alone program ?